# How to transform POST body response to get the elements?

Tags: elixir, elixir-poison

I am making a web request using `HTTPoison` in Elixir:

```
HTTPpoison.post "http://localhost:3000/mymodels"," {\"param1\": \"#{value1}\" ,  \"param2\":\"#{value2}\"} ", [{"Content-Type", "application/json"}]
```

This is the response I get:

```
{:ok,
 %HTTPoison.Response{body: "{\"id\":46,\"result\":18,\"param1\":\"liqueur\",\"param2\":\"quif\"}",
  headers: [{"X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"},
   {"X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block"}, {"X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"},
   {"Location", "http://localhost:3000/mymodels/46"},
   {"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
   {"ETag", "W/\"05b8c75e0a5288c835651f48d4b8a80a\""},
   {"Cache-Control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"},
   {"X-Request-Id", "1e8ae2d3-073a-4779-916a-edffc38f8b5a"},
   {"X-Runtime", "0.530440"}, {"Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"}],
  status_code: 201}}
```

I'm new to Elixir and my problem is I want to get the `results` element from the `response.body`

```
iex(3)> response.body           
"{\"id\":46,\"results\":18,\"param1\":\"liqueur\",\"param2\":\"quif\"}"
```

I am not sure how to convert this string to an array/hash or stuple in Elixir. I have at Enum, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`response.body` is a JSON encoded string. You need to use a JSON parser to parse it to the appropriate Elixir data structure first. With [`Poison`](https://github.com/devinus/poison), you'd use `Poison.decode!/1`:

```
iex(1)> body = "{\"id\":46,\"results\":18,\"param1\":\"liqueur\",\"param2\":\"quif\"}"
"{\"id\":46,\"results\":18,\"param1\":\"liqueur\",\"param2\":\"quif\"}"
iex(2)> json = Poison.decode!(body)
%{"id" => 46, "param1" => "liqueur", "param2" => "quif", "results" => 18}
iex(3)> json["results"]
18
```

Comment: Great thanks Dogbert, after putting  the Poison dependency I was back on. I think Elixir is great.